# Override Spring properties without using profiles

Tags: spring-boot

I have few property files(application.properties) which contains both custom and spring configuration under classpath, i want load these properties based on system variables.
I used `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer`  to load properties as below.

```
@Bean
    public PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer loadResources() {
PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer resourceConfigurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
        resourceConfigurer.setLocations(new ClassPathResource("file1"), new ClassPathResource("file2"));
return resourceConfigurer ;
}
```

But it failed to override spring configuration(spring configurations added in application.properties), i want to override these files after spring picks application.properties file.
Idea is to override spring configuration programmatically.
How this can be achieved?

Comment: Why? This will add only additional processing to the application and indeed will not override things (it might even break the Spring Boot processing). Run the application with `--spring.config.location` or `--spring.config-additional-location` instead of trying this. See [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config) on how to load additional files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve above using `EnvironmentPostProcessor`.

[spring doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.x-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-application-events-and-listeners)